# Calculating total Asleep time from HealthKit using Swift

Tags: swift, healthkit

Got another question!  I'm trying to calculate the total time asleep from the health app.  I'm able to get the information using the following:

```
func readSleepAnalysis(date: Date) {

    if let mindfulType = HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.sleepAnalysis) {

        let startDate = convertStartDate(StartDate: date)
        let endDate = convertEndDate(EndDate: date)
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: .strictStartDate)

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending: false)

        let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: mindfulType, predicate: predicate, limit: 30, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (query, tmpResult, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                    print("Something went wrong getting sleep analysis: \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
            if let result = tmpResult {

                for item in result {
                    if let sample = item as? HKCategorySample {
                        let value = (sample.value == HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysis.inBed.rawValue) ? "InBed" : "Asleep"
                            print("Healthkit sleep: \(sample.startDate) \(sample.endDate) value: \(value)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        healthKit.execute(query)
    }
}
```

However, I am getting:

Healthkit sleep: 2020-04-13 01:27:55 +0000 2020-04-13 11:49:51 +0000 value: InBed

Healthkit sleep: 2020-04-13 02:46:41 +0000 2020-04-13 11:49:51 +0000 value: Asleep

Healthkit sleep: 2020-04-12 07:48:06 +0000 2020-04-12 12:32:59 +0000 value: Asleep

Healthkit sleep: 2020-04-12 04:18:33 +0000 2020-04-12 07:17:29 +0000 value: Asleep

What I am trying to get is only the sum of the Asleep time in hours:minutes.

Any suggestions or comments, as always, is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this?